# Flex does not handle line breaks in htmlText

Tags: apache-flex, rich-text-editor, htmltext

I store the `htmlText` property of a `RichTextEditor` in the database.

I retrieve it in another instance and I want to show the user the **first line** of it as **plain text**

So I let Flex handle the conversion by using a function like this

```
var editor:TextField = new TextField();
editor.htmlText = htmlTextFromDb;
var converted:String = editor.text;
```

However, the issue is that this conversion does not handle lines properly. I get everything in one line!

Lets say what I get from the database is this

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">This is line one</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">This is line two</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

As soon as I say `editor.htmlText = htmlTextFromDb`, editor.htmlText becomes

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">This is line oneThis is line two</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

It acts as if new lines are not present.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about server side conversion of this HTML text.

<strike>But in AS only you could do it line by line by splitting on line break, then converting the line to text and after this concatenating all. A bit ugly, but should work.</strike>

```
var editor:TextField = new TextField();
var result:Array = new Array();
var input:Array = htmlTextFromDb.split(/\n/);
for each( var line:String in input) {
    editor.htmlText = line;
    result.push(editor.text);
}
var converted:String = result.join("\n");
```

## edit

Replacing the tags with regular expression would be another way. First replace the closing paragraph `</P>` with a line break, and then remove all remaining tags.

```
var lnRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp("</P>", "g");
s = s.replace(lnRegExp, "\n");
var tagRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp("<([^>\\s]+)(\\s[^>]+)*>", "g");
trace(s.replace(tagRegExp, ""));
```

Comment: Sorry! It doesn't work. The problem is that htmlTextFromDb does not have \n's. From the looks of it, it uses <p> tags to handle new lines.

Comment: Then your code snippet in your question is misleading, because you've posted your database output with a line break.

Comment: Oops sorry! The line break was added for clarity! I'll fix that :)